# replace string that includes a wildcard

Tags: string, powershell, replace, wildcard, regexp-replace

Would someone be able to advise me on this, please?

The source file (filename `sourcetrans.txt`) content includes path and row number eg:

```
C:\temp\TRANSFile1.txt:1001:DTRANS       1.111111111                   12345667889       debit  product1           
C:\temp\TRANSFile1.txt:20002:DTRANS       2.222222222                  23143453456       credit product2                
C:\temp\TRANSFile1.txt:300:DTRANS       3.333333333                    23443655678       debit  product3
```

I'm trying to extract the `debit` rows only and redirect output to another file but I also wish to remove the file path and row number from the start of each row ie remove this string:

```
C:\temp\TRANSFile1.txt:1001:
C:\temp\TRANSFile1.txt:300:
```

so the desired output being:

```
DTRANS       1.111111111                   12345667889       debit  product1                         
DTRANS       3.333333333                   23443655678       debit  product3
```

It was going quite well with the below command

```bash
(
  Get-Content "C:\temp\sourcetrans.txt" |
  where {$_ -like "C:\temp\TRANSFile1.txt:*debit*"}
).Replace('C:\temp\TRANSFile1.txt:','') |
  Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\SSFinal.txt -append
```

and the output file `SSfinal.txt`:

```
1001:DTRANS      1.111111111                   12345667889       debit  product1                          
300:DTRANS       3.333333333                    23443655678       debit  product3
```

However, the output still contains the row number.
I thought it would be a simple case of using `*` wildcard to filter out the row number eg:

```bash
(
  Get-Content "C:\temp\sourcetrans.txt" | 
  where {$_ -like "C:\temp\TRANSFile1.txt:*debit*"}
).Replace('C:\temp\TRANSFile1.txt:*:','') |
  Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\SSFinal.txt -append
```

However this doesn't work, including the `*` returns the full string again including the filepath and row number. Any advice greatly appreciated.

Expected:

```
DTRANS       1.111111111                   12345667889       debit  product1                         
DTRANS       3.333333333                   23443655678       debit  product3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) .NET method only supports *literal* replacements (it doesn't support [wildcard expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Wildcards) or [regexes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)).

By contrast, PowerShell's [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator is *regex*-based, so using it instead of `.Replace()` is one option (I'm using a single input line as an example; see the next section for a complete solution):

```bash
# Remove everything up to and including 
# the ":" after the number following the path.
$line -replace '^.:.+?:.+?:'
```

Another option is to use the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator:

```bash
# Split the line into at most 4 ":"-separated tokens and extract the last one.
($line -split ':', 4)[-1]
```

---

However, you can also use the regex-based [`-match`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#-match-and--notmatch) operator in your `where` ([`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object)) call to both match only the lines of interest *and* use a capture group (`(…)`) to capture only the relevant *part* of each line of interest, which can then be accessed via the [automatic `$Matches` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#matches) in a subsequent [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call:

```bash
Get-Content C:\temp\sourcetrans.txt | 
  Where-Object { $_ -match '^.:.+?:.+?:(.*debit.*)$' }
  ForEach-Object { $Matches[1] } |
  Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\SSFinal.txt -Append
```

<sup>Note: `-Append` is only needed if you need to append content to a *preexisting file*.</sup>

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/jqLsaI/1).